# How to return data from databse in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

**BACKGROUND INFO**
Currently I am making a project in Django (Online system for students and teachers), I have finished frontend, but I have run into a problem with backend. So when I try to export data from one of the models, it returned none.
**CODE**
Relevant part of the models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Ustanova(models.Model):
    skola = models.CharField(max_length = 10)   
    programu = models.CharField(max_length = 50) 
    slika = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.skola + '-' + self.program_u

class Razred(models.Model):
    ustanova = models.ForeignKey(Ustanova, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    programr  = models.CharField(max_length = 50)  
    razredr = models.CharField(max_length = 10)  
    is_take = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.razred_r + '-' + self.program_r
```

Relevant part of views,py:

```
def _class_chooser(request, name):
    ustanova = get_object_or_404(Ustanova, skola = name)
    razred = Razred.objects.filter(razredr__startswith = name).all()
    context ={
        "ustanova" : ustanova,
        "razred": razred,
    }
```

url is in format:
`path('<str:name>/', views._class_chooser, name ="class_chooser"),`
So *www.example.hr/students/XVG/* is page for students of XVG (class chooser page).

And let's say that data is html file is represented with ul/li:

```
<ul>
    {% for i in ustanova.razred_set.all %}
        <li><a href ="{% url 'students:class_menu' razred.razredr %}">  {{ razred.razredr}} - {{ razred.programr }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**ISSUE**
Now we are coming to the issue, in html file, everything related to ustanova class is working, so `{% for i in ustanova.razred_set.all %}` is showing right number of classes stored in database, but `{{ razred.razredr}}`, or enything related to Razred class is not working (no errors while running server, or opening page), if I try to manual go to *www.exapmle.hr/name/class/*, I am getting Django Debug error (404). Did I do anything wrong with views query, or something else is wrong? Thank You in advance.
**P.S.**
*Example:* Let*s say that some institution(ABC) has 5 classes, class chooser would look like this(without css/js):

```
ABC
-
-
-
-
-
```

So only dot before class mark and program is showed.

Comment: where is `razred_set` defined?

Comment: Razred is connectd to Ustanova with foreign key,  ustanova is object of Ustanova, and _set is Django query, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iterator is `i` (`for i in ...`), but you're accessing `razred`.

Change the iterator to `razred` too and you should be all good.

```
<ul>
  {% for razred in ustanova.razred_set.all %}
     <li>
       <a href="{% url 'students:class_menu' razred.razredr %}">
           {{ razred.razredr}} - {{ razred.programr }}
       </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to you code `razred` is queryset, not a model instance:

```
razred = Razred.objects.filter(razredr__startswith = name).all()
```

so you can't address it directly like a single record here:

```
<li><a href ="{% url 'students:class_menu' razred.razredr %}">  {{ razred.razredr}} - {{ razred.programr }}</a></li>
```

Instead change your code in this way:

```
{% for razred in ustanova.razred_set.all %}
    <li><a href ="{% url 'students:class_menu' razred.razredr %}">  {{ razred.razredr}} - {{ razred.programr }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

and also remove redundant `razred` query from view.